# Upcasting to an Interface<Foo> when a class implements generic Interface<T> with type constraint T=Foo?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I've got an interface declaring a few methods (in C#):

```
internal interface ILetter<T> where T:IEntity
{
    List<T> GetRecords();
    DocumentParameters GetDocumentParameters(T record);
    void MarkRecordAsHandled(T record, bool letterSent);
}
```

I also have an abstract class implementing the above interface, adding a bunch of general functionality as well. It looks something like this:

```
abstract class AbstractLetter<T> : ILetter<T> where T:IEntity
{
    public abstract List<T> GetRecords();

    public abstract DocumentParameters GetDocumentParameters(T record);

    public abstract void MarkRecordAsHandled(T record, bool letterSent);

    protected readonly FamisContext FamisContext = new FamisContext();

    protected bool KnownEmail(string socialSecurityNumber){ doing stuff }
}
```

Finally I have different classes inheriting from the above base class (AbstractLetter). They, of course, include specific implementations of the methods declared in the interface.
I'd like to make a batch-job, creating the different kind of letters, based on the methods from the interface. I thought I could do this by making a list and then iterate through the list using the same methods on each element. But apparently I cannot do that - at least not without explicitly type casting them.
So, my question is: Can I do something like the below, but without the typecasting (and more letters, of course)?

```
var test = new List<ILetter<IEntity>> {new JobTrainingLetter() as ILetter<IEntity>};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully sure I understand your question, but is this what you're after?

http://ideone.com/bE08rw

In LinqPad:

```
interface IEntity
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class FooEntity : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public FooEntity()
    {
        Name = "foo";
    }
}

interface ILetter<T> where T:IEntity
{
    string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    List<T> GetRecords();
}


abstract class AbstractLetter<T> : ILetter<T> where T:IEntity
{
    public abstract string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    public abstract List<T> GetRecords();
}

class JobLetter : AbstractLetter<FooEntity>
{
    public override string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    public override List<FooEntity> GetRecords() { return null; }

    public JobLetter()
    {
        var entity = new FooEntity();
        EntityMetadata = entity.Name;
    }
}

List<T> CreateLetterList<T, K>() where T : AbstractLetter<K>, new() where K : IEntity
{
    return new List<T> { new T(), };
}

void Main()
{
    var jobLetterList = CreateLetterList<JobLetter, FooEntity>();
    foreach (var letter in jobLetterList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(letter.EntityMetadata);
    }
}
```

To cater for a List that stores multiple types of letters:

```
abstract class AbstractLetter: ILetter<IEntity>
{
    public abstract string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    public abstract List<IEntity> GetRecords();
}

class JobLetter<T> : AbstractLetter where T : IEntity, new()
{
    public override string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    public override List<IEntity> GetRecords() { return null; }

    public JobLetter()
    {
        var entity = new T();
        EntityMetadata = entity.Name;
    }
}

class SubsidyLetter<T> : AbstractLetter where T : IEntity, new()
{
    public override string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    public override List<IEntity> GetRecords() { return null; }

    public SubsidyLetter()
    {
        var entity = new T();
        EntityMetadata = entity.Name;
    }
}
List<T> CreateLetterList<T>() where T : AbstractLetter, new()
{
    return new List<T> { new T(), };
}

void Main()
{
    var jobLetterList = CreateLetterList<JobLetter<FooEntity>>();
    var subsidyLetterList = CreateLetterList<SubsidyLetter<FooEntity2>>();

    var mergedList = new List<AbstractLetter>();
    mergedList.Add(jobLetterList[0]);
    mergedList.Add(subsidyLetterList[0]);

    foreach (var letter in mergedList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(letter.EntityMetadata);
    }
}
```

As you can see you will lose some type information in the base class.

To support what you're trying to achieve (but not necessarily the required functionality) you need valid variance on your types:

```
interface ILetter<out T> where T:IEntity
{
    string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<T> GetRecords();
}


abstract class AbstractLetter<T> : ILetter<T> where T:IEntity
{
    public abstract string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetRecords();
}

class JobLetter : AbstractLetter<FooEntity>
{
    public override string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    public override IEnumerable<FooEntity> GetRecords() { return null; }

    public JobLetter()
    {
        var entity = new FooEntity();
        EntityMetadata = entity.Name;
    }
}

class SubsidyLetter : AbstractLetter<FooEntity2>
{
    public override string EntityMetadata { get; set; }
    public override IEnumerable<FooEntity2> GetRecords() { return null; }

    public SubsidyLetter()
    {
        var entity = new FooEntity2();
        EntityMetadata = entity.Name;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var jobLetterList = CreateLetterList<JobLetter, FooEntity>();
    var subsidyLetterList = CreateLetterList<SubsidyLetter, FooEntity2>();
    var mergedList = new List<ILetter<IEntity>>();

    mergedList.Add(jobLetterList[0]);
    mergedList.Add(subsidyLetterList[0]);

    foreach (var letter in mergedList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(letter.EntityMetadata);
    }
}
```

IEnumerable will work in place of List as it doesn't allow you to put values into it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in the OP. None the less, you got really close. Continuing on your code, add another FooEntity2 and the class `class SubsidyLetter : AbstractLetter<FooEntity2> { }`. What I'd like is to have a list containing both a SubsidyLetter and a JobLetter. Is that possible with your suggesting?

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'll have to figure out a way to work around that. Thank you for your time anyway. I'll approve your solution as the right answer, even though it doesn't quite do what I hoped for.

Comment: See my last edit about replacing List with a type that supports covariance.

Answer (score 3):

Well, starters, `new JobTrainingLetter() as ILetter<IEntity>` is not really valid, unless you mark `T` explictly as an "**out**", that is, [covariant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

If you mark a type parameter `out`, you should also ensure that the `T` can be accessed only from the "output" positions.

It does not really make sense to treat your letter as `ILetter<IEntity>`, as that would mean that you have access to methods such as:

`DocumentParameters GetDocumentParameters(IEntity record);`

on an instance of `ILetter<YourConcreteEntity>`. What would happen if you try `GetDocumentParameters(anotherConcreteEntity)`? **Runtime exception.**

I suggest you to think about your design a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Your base class is defined as:

```
abstract class AbstractLetter<T> : ILetter<T> where T:IEntity
```

The `T` is bound with a generic constraint, but the constraints are not part of the type signatures (and also co/contravariance is not supported for classes, it's just for interfaces, not that you have any here anyways). So, your class, for the compiler, from the inheritance point of view, really looks something like *):

```
abstract class AbstractLetter<T> : ILetter<T>
```

which does not tell the compiler that it implements `ILetter<IEntity>`.

Simply add that part explicitely:

```
abstract class AbstractLetter<T> : ILetter<IEntity>, ILetter<T> where T:IEntity
```

Of course it may force you to add some code to satisfy that extra interface (you can have VS generate them for you and fill with pass-forwards to the current code), but it will work.

EDIT: Oor, you can use variance settings on the interface like ChrisEelmaa wisely suggested (I'm suprised I didn't thought of it, even after mentioning variance, heh!). But that won't work directly with current method set. I also don't recommend creating two interfaces `ILetter<int T> + ILetter2<out T>` - this almost always leads to bloat and really weird and complicated code. Too complicated comparing to a few casts.

*) whole this paragraph is a really really loose description

Comment: You're eventually lifting the covariance compile time restriction that `T` can't appear both on out/in positions, thus by definition, one of the `ILetter<IEntity>` functions on `AbstractLetter<T>` has to throw exception on runtime / add explicit check :P